# Create Do While loop in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I need to create something like this using DAX. Preferably highlighted columns as two columns of a table. I have managed to set the preview of the requirement But I'm unable to proceed with it. Hope someone can help me with this.

[image]

I have tried with DAX queries, but it won't give me what I need to be done.

Comment: Misconception: This is not what DAX is made for. Try HTML instead ;)

Comment: Hi @Peter, 
I just wanted to get the calculations done as per the amount field. 

The initial value available in the amount field (8), should be multiplied by the percentage (90%). 

After the first record, it should consider the previous row value of the amount field when multiplying from the percentage.

Comment: There is no recursion or cycles in DAX. You can try cumulative measure, or selective measure or `Switch()` + `Isinscope()`, or different approach, but not a loop.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mik. But I have only minimal experience with DAX. I couldn't figure out how to write this code. If you could help me with this it will be a great help

Comment: If I understood you corectly you want to have a flexible visual. What is a maximal possible loopls number?

Comment: There’s a simple formula for that: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest

Answer (score 0):

This feels more like a Power Query to me. Try pasting this into a blank query in the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    StartingValue = 8,
    Deduction = 0.10,
    StartDate = #date(2023,2,14),
    Times=6,
    #"Multiplier" = 1 - Deduction, 
    Source = Table.FromList({1..Times}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), type table [Index=Int64.Type], null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Add Amount" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Amount", each StartingValue * Number.Power(#"Multiplier",[Index]-1), type number),  
    #"Add Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Amount", "Date", each Date.AddMonths(StartDate,[Index]-1), type date)
in
    #"Add Date"
```

[image]

You can change the 4 input values into Parameters and make this a function in Power Query to easily create new tables.
[image]

Comment: I afraid that OP wants to have a flexible visual, not a static table.

Comment: For it to be a dynamic table based on other data tables, we need more details on where the inputs are coming from and how this is to be used. My assumption was a separate report would be created for each analysis with a given set of inputs.